# How to install a bin file to a particular target location?

Tags: installation, scripts

I need to install a bin file.

My home dir is `/home/user`.
The bin file is present at `/apps/ba/software`.
I need to install this at `/apps/ba/ins`.

How can I do that?

Comment: When you say "install a bin file", do you mean that you have a `.deb` installation file? Or do you mean that you want to copy the executable file to `/apps/ba/ins` and add it to your path? Or something else? (This is an unusual request; you are encouraged to use the package manager to install applications. The package manager prevents conflicts, automatically installs dependencies, automatically updates packages, and lets you uninstall very easily.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you could add args: `--prefix=dir` if you compile source code to install your software, but if you install it with the `apt-get` command you can not specify the install location.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing from source, try `./configure --prefix=/apps/ba/ins && make && make install`
If you are installing via apt best way is to create a symlink:

```
ln -s  /apps/ba/ins /apps/ba/software
```